# How to retry CloudKit's async query method after a delay

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, cloudkit

I'm using the new async CloudKit [.records](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabase/3856524-records) method:

```
var (matchResults, queryCursor) = try await CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.MyDB")
    .publicCloudDatabase
    .records(matching: query)
```

And I want to protect my app from CloudKit errors, some CloudKit errors are recoverable and contain the `retryAfterSeconds` property. And I need to use this property to set a delay and retry.

I came up with this:

```
do {
    var (matchResults, queryCursor) = try await CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.MyDB")
        .publicCloudDatabase
        .records(matching: query)
} catch {
    if let ckError = error as? CKError {
        //It's a CloudKit error, check if it has retryAfterSeconds
        if let retryAfterSeconds = ckError.retryAfterSeconds {
            //Rerun this func after a delay 
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + retryAfterSeconds) { [weak self] in
                await self?.fetchNewItems() // I get an error: 'async' call in a function that does not support concurrency
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't run an async function from `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`, what do?

I know I can add `Task.sleep(nanoseconds: ...)` in between, but that route doesn't look good to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter equivalent in Structured Concurrency in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76340926/dispatchqueue-main-asyncafter-equivalent-in-structured-concurrency-in-swift)

Comment: Yes it does, `Task.sleep(nanoseconds: ...)` it is.